# Powering USB Cable From Different Head

Tags: usb, power-supply, cable, wiring

I Have a Mikrotik RB951UI-2HND router, and a Huawei E5577 Modem Wi-Fi with modded firmware so it can run without battery (directly from power source). So I want to connect the two together with USB Cable. The problem is that the router doesn't supply enough power for the modem. One possible solution is to buy a powered USB port. But I honestly don't want to buy any extra stuff.

So I search for USB cable diagram and cut and connect USB cable that I have lying around. What I want to try to make is a USB Y cable with two male Type A USB, and one type B micro USB.

First, I try connecting the power cable (red and black) from one of the type A to the type B. Then the data cable (green and white) from the other type A to the same type B. The modem did turn on, but the router didn't detect it.

Secondly, I try connecting the power cable from both type A to the type B, and then the data cable from one of the type A to the type B. I connect the Data + Power USB to the modem and the power only to power source (5V 2A), and the micro to the modem. The modem turn on, and the router detect it, but the modem still turn off after a few minutes. I time it, and the time it took for the modem to turn off with USB cable only from the router, and the one with power source is the same (aroun 60 to 90 seconds). And just a note, the modem still stay turn on with only the power source cable connected with Y cable or normal USB.

Can someone explain why this doesn't work?

Thank You Very Much

Edited:
Here is the diagram of my tries

[First Try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DnpH.png)

[Second Try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCngd.png)

And the third try from the comment suggestion [Third Try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj1LH.png)

The third one does actually work. The modem is on and the router detect it. But after a while my modem still turn off again. Then I tested it without connected to the router and it still turn off. I think, between the time I modified this cable, the quality (if you can say it like that) or voltage of the cable decrease. The method that I use to connect the cable is to just open the skin and then connect the copper wire together with bare hands. After some searching I found out about Voltage Drop. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand.  It spunds like your 5v, 2 amp supply.migjt not be enough, and/or the router is syncing current.  I wonder if, if you modified your second cable sich that there was no +5v connected to the router if it might work? (ie leave the ground connected to all 3 devices?

Comment: The power supply is sufficient. If you read my story i said that both time with y cable (router not connected) and normal cable the modem turn on.

Comment: (Your images are all the same, btw).  While its possible the issue is a voltage drop, if that is the case either the wire is to small or power supply is not supplying enough current.  Increasing the physical size (ie of the copper) of the cables or shortening the cables will reduce power loss, soldering might have a tiny effect as well.

Comment: Looking at this, the Huawei E5577  is NOT a modem, its a wireless router/hotspot. Do you have a multimeter?  If so, why not simply measure the voltage on the cable when plugged in.  If its less then 4.9 volts its not providing enough power.  Also, can you confirm that the battery is not connected to the Huawei when plugged in to the cable?  (If it is, it could be a serious source of power drain)

Comment: Yes, but the E5577 can be used as a modem. I have used one connected to my laptop and connected to the internet through the USB cable. And the router did detect the device as LTE in the interface list. For the battery, it already broken a long time ago, hence why I modded it in the first place so that I can still use it. And no, I don't have a multimeter.